# Add text to image automatically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, imagemagick

Is there a way to add text onto an image via an automated fashion, such as what http://www.pinwords.com/ can do? I'm using Rails so anything that's API driven or Rails compatible would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.imagemagick.org/ can do many different kinds of image manipulation including adding text. It has a ruby interface.

Comment: Apparently imageMagick is already part of heroku.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963892/heroku-running-imagemagick-w-paperclip
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/heroku/Ba4xEHutj84