# "Errno::ENOENT in ListingsController#create" in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick-convert, minimagick

After adding `include CarrierWave::MiniMagick` to my `image_uploader.rb` file as well as uncommenting the `process: resize to fit => [200,300]` line inside of `image_uploader.rb`, whenever I attempt to create a new Listing in my app I receive the following error message:

```
"Errno::ENOENT in ListingsController#create" with the explanation of "No such file or directory - identify".
```

It appears the error is occurring in the directory of `'app/controllers/listings_controller.rb'` on line 20 inside the "Create" action.

Description of extracted source on the error page shows this: 
`self.pid = Process.spawn({'LANG' => self.lang}, command, log_opts)`
as the line raising an error.

Prior to these two mentioned changes, the new Listing would be created with no issue whatsoever (apart from the attached image being much too large, hence my newest change). I'm using Cloud9 IDE to develop this application, with Puma as my web server, and Heroku as the (intended) future production-grade app host.

Comment: Turns out I didn't have ImageMagick installed in my Cloud9 IDE workstation; run "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get install ImageMagick" to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No such file or directory - identify

This is mean that ImageMagick package isn't installed in your OS. So, try to find way to install ImageMagick package to your Heroku node.

**Update**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963953/2398521) answer says that ImageMagic is installed to Heroku already. So, try to add Ruby wrapper of ImageMagick to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.1.0'
```

Comment: Turns out I hadn't installed ImageMagick into my Cloud9 Rails IDE workstation! Your answer helped get me started in the right direction however :) To anyone else wondering how to fix this error, i simply ran 'sudo apt-get update' in the workstation terminal, then 'sudo apt-get install ImageMagick'